# Connection of signals and slots (regarding qlistview) - Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I need to connect a singal and a slot but I can't seem to figure out it's structure, I need to connect a qlistview double click and I need the number starting from the top that the element was in, for example, if I had a qlistview with 5 elements, and you clicked the 2nd one I need to know that the second element was clicked. In use I'm doing a network connection and the qlistview shows the aviable networks.

Summing up I would like to know the snippet of code I have to use to achieve this because I can't figure it out.

Comment: I'd start by reading the documentation of [QAbstractItemView::doubleClicked](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#doubleClicked) (`QListView` inherits `QAbstractItemView`, what you can also see in the doc)

Comment: @Jonas I managed to execute a function when the item was double clicked, however,  I can't seem to get the position id.

Comment: @xander I already tried that, It works just fine, I managed to execute a function when the item was double clicked but I can't seem to get the id of the qlistview item.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: What "id" do you mean? Post some code what you have already and what you're expecting. The list view generally holds no data, that depends on the implementation of your list model to retrieve some data of the clicked item I guess.

Comment: @xander as I explained in my question, I would like to know the id of the element in the list, for example a list composed by 5 elements, in case I double clicked the 3rd element I would like to get returned "3"

Comment: ok so you just need the row index!? if you read the documenation (link I provided in the first comment): "The item the mouse was double-clicked on is specified by index." so you have the index already. Qt model view classes work with abstract `QModelIndex`, if you just need the index itself use `int row = index.row()`. Maybe you should read the [introduction to Qt's model view classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) to get a general idea how everything is connected.

Comment: @xander alright, that is what I wanted to know, thanks a lot, could you post it as an answer so I can't mark it as solved ?

Comment: ok, but that would be much easier to solve if you posted some code that you actually had the signal connection and everything, that was not clear in the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the row index of the clicked item you can simply access the `QModelIndex` in the `doubleClicked` slot of your `QListView`, e.g.

```
int row = index.row();
```

Maybe you should read the [introduction to Qt's model view classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) to get a general idea how everything is connected.